# Twig grouping items based on resolution

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, twig

I have a for loop that iterates through divs and groups them using batch, my grouping size needs to change based on resolution so on mobile batch should be 1 and on the desktop it should be 4 incrementing through resolutions.

How can I achieve that in twig/drupal?

```
{% for column in items|batch(4) %}
                <div {{ attributes.addClass('swiper-slide').removeClass(classes, 'field--items', 'swiper-wrapper') }}>
                    {% for item in column %}
                        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You don't, u'd resort to CSS and mediaqueries in particular

Answer (score 0):

Twig work on server side, It cannot know the resolution of the device. You might use a library to detect user's device by their `User-Agent` in **request header** like http://mobiledetect.net/

---

If you working on a responsive project, consider using CSS @media queries for multiple resolutions.